# Extracting integer from json using Python 2.7

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract the integer values from the 'count" key per below and am getting into trouble with string indices errors. Can someone provide a method to do this?

```
 "comments":[
    {
      "name":"Courtneylee",
      "count":97
    },
    {
      "name":"Geraldine",
      "count":96
    },
    {
      "name":"Aisling",
      "count":96
    },
    {
      "name":"Millar",
      "count":93
    },
    {
      "name":"Aeryn",
      "count":92
    },
    {
      "name":"Emilylee",
      "count":92
    },
    {
      "name":"Clodagh",
      "count":92
    },
    {
      "name":"Madelaine",
      "count":91
    },
    {
      "name":"Amyrose",
      "count":89
    },
    {
      "name":"Kael",
      "count":85
    },
    {
      "name":"Ngonidzashe",
      "count":83
    },
    {
      "name":"Zayn",
      "count":83
    },
    {
      "name":"Jordy",
      "count":80
    },
    {
      "name":"Tyane",
      "count":78
    },
    {
      "name":"Hussnan",
      "count":78
    },
    {
      "name":"Karly",
      "count":70
    },
    {
      "name":"Matej",
      "count":70
    },
    {
      "name":"Reena",
      "count":68
    },
    {
      "name":"Abigayle",
      "count":68
    },
    {
      "name":"Karamvir",
      "count":67
    },
    {
      "name":"Kaleigh",
      "count":66
    },
    {
      "name":"Roba",
      "count":65
    },
    {
      "name":"Harjyot",
      "count":65
    },
    {
      "name":"Attila",
      "count":64
    },
    {
      "name":"Dharam",
      "count":62
    },
    {
      "name":"Marcin",
      "count":56
    },
    {
      "name":"Ruaidhri",
      "count":56
    },
    {
      "name":"Adenn",
      "count":51
    },
    {
      "name":"Saschamarie",
      "count":50
    },
    {
      "name":"Rylie",
      "count":49
    },
    {
      "name":"Alieu",
      "count":48
    },
    {
      "name":"Caidy",
      "count":43
    },
    {
      "name":"Kaila",
      "count":40
    },
    {
      "name":"Declain",
      "count":39
    },
    {
      "name":"Owyn",
      "count":37
    },
    {
      "name":"Gurthar",
      "count":35
    },
    {
      "name":"Brandon",
      "count":33
    },
    {
      "name":"Mustafa",
      "count":32
    },
    {
      "name":"Dion",
      "count":31
    },
    {
      "name":"Meenal",
      "count":22
    },
    {
      "name":"Kyan",
      "count":20
    },
    {
      "name":"Karis",
      "count":18
    },
    {
      "name":"Christabel",
      "count":12
    },
    {
      "name":"Kerryanne",
      "count":12
    },
    {
      "name":"Martha",
      "count":10
    },
    {
      "name":"Helena",
      "count":9
    },
    {
      "name":"Rumaysa",
      "count":7
    },
    {
      "name":"Rosalind",
      "count":5
    },
    {
      "name":"Florin",
      "count":4
    },
    {
      "name":"Melisa",
      "count":3
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using and the traceback?

Comment: The json is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

```
data = {'comments':[...]} #Your dict
for item in data['comments']:
    print item['count'] #Whatever operation you want with your number
```

Comment: The OP hasn't mentioned that he has a dictionary. The title of the question indicates he has a json

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using and the error you are getting??

Comment: import json
import urllib

url = raw_input('Enter - ')
java = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
print java

info = json.loads(java)
#print info

for item in info:
    print item['comments'][{'count'}][0]

Comment: The error I'm getting (wanted to show a snippet) is TypeError: string indices must be integers for line 12

Comment: @ MCSH, The json is not invalid